# get periodic updates from server in my J2ME App

Tags: java-me

I'm writing a J2ME application that should get periodic updates server. how do i implement the functionality using J2ME?I am planning to deploy the application it on symbian platform...thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

check MIDP 2 [Push Registry](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/)

> The push registry enables MIDlets to set themselves up to be launched automatically, without user initiation. The push registry manages network- and timer-initiated MIDlet activation; that is, it enables an inbound network connection or a timer-based alarm to wake a MIDlet up. For example, you can write a workgroup application that employs network activation to wake up and process newly received email, or new appointments that have been scheduled. Or you can use timer-based activation to schedule your MIDlet to synchronize with a server every so often then go to sleep...